# Reasons not to use VARCHAR for database fields that will hold user inputted data?

Tags: database, validation

Assuming I don't care about database optimisation, is there a reason I shouldn't just use VARCHAR for every field in a database that will store user inputted data?

Defining data types in the database seems to be duplicating the work of validation functions.

To put another way, what's the single source of truth for validating inputted data? The database field definition, or the validation functions that first parse the incoming data?

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of validation, I would store values as their natural data types in the database.  By storing everything as `varchar`, you make it harder to use aggregate functions (`SUM`, `AVG`, etc.), and functions that work with specific data types, like Sql Server's date time functions (`DATEADD`, `DATEDIFF`, etc.).

Comment: +1 exactly - if it talks like an `INT`, walks like an `INT`, smells like an `INT` - it **IS** an `INT` so store it that way!